# Why does `du -sh *` complain about invalid options?

Tags: shell-script, wildcards, disk-usage, options

I've searched my best through Google, but for the life of me I can't figure out what to use instead of `*` (asterisk) after a recent update (even Wikipedia seems to think

`du -sh * and du -sh *` should work)

I've used

`du -sh * | sort -h`

ever since just before sort got the `-h` option (on Fedora I think, took a while before I could use the `sort -h` on CentOS), but suddenly * seems to output a long list of

```
du: invalid option -- ' '
```

where the `' '` goes through all the invalid options not mentioned in the man page.

I would be very thankful if someone could tell me what would be the equivalent of

`du -sh * | sort -h`

on the updated versions.

Comment: [Should be `du -sh ./*` or `du -sh -- *`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110750)

Comment: @jmkane Your command works on Fedora 21

Answer (score 17):

You have a file with a funny name, probably starting with a `-`. Remember that globs (like `*`) are expanded by your shell, *not* the command being run. As an example, say you have:

```
$ ls -1
foo
-q
```

Simple enough directory, with two files in it. (The `-1` option to coreutils `ls` makes its output single-column.)

When you run `du -sh *`, the shell notices that the second argument contains a special character (`*`) and isn't quoted, so it does glob expansion. It expands it to everything that matches, in this case `foo` and `-q`. The effect is exactly as if you'd run:

```
$ du -sh foo -q
du: invalid option -- 'q'
Try 'du --help' for more information.
```

The error above is clear: GNU utilities allow options mixed with file names for convenience; `du` is taking the file name `-q` as an option. And there isn't a `-q` option. (This is actually the best you can expect; worse would be if there were a `-q` option, and it did something unwanted.)

Stépahane's suggestion is to change your glob to `./*`, which would result in `du -sh ./foo ./-q`—which of course is taken as a file name, because it no longer begins with `-`. The other option he suggests is to use `--`, which tells GNU utilities that there are no more options—only file/directory names.

Really you should *always* use either `… ./*` or `… -- *` instead of `*`, but we're all lazy…. Just be careful, especially if you don't trust all the file names.

Comment: ok, my bug report is already send now, but I added a link to this question, so if @jmkane could look if this is the case, it would help the devs to know if they have to search for a bug or not. I did´t know this, never had any files on my system starting with -, but nice to know this.

Comment: Note that `--` is not just GNU but POSIX too so should be honored by most `du` implementations.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I can still use du -sh * in other folders, so it must be something new in the folder I've checked regularly, but I can't see anything obvious, and I'll make sure to use ./* or -- * in the future.

Answer (score 4):

du is taking the dash in the file and taking it as an argument.

If you pass '--' to the command, that signifies no further options will be sent, so run the command like this:
du -fh -- * or du -sh -- *

worked for me...

this thread helped out :-http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1354139

Comment: Putting a double-dash at the end of the flag list fixed this, IMO this should be the accepted answer.