# scp `ls -liart | tail -n5 | grep 0001` wuxi-jump-128:/tmp fails: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, pipe, scp

I hope to make scp work with pipe, like

```
firstlove@chenli ~/Downloads $ ls -liart | tail -n5 | grep 0001                                  
51384329 -rw-r--r--  1 firstlove firstlove       1440 Oct 31 13:02 0001-add-UNA_PRINT-for-unalign-access-info.patch
51384385 -rw-r--r--  1 firstlove firstlove       3028 Oct 31 13:02 0001-support-new-em_machine.patch
firstlove@chenli ~/Downloads $ scp `ls -liart | tail -n5 | grep 0001` wuxi-jump-128:/tmp         
deepin@172.16.17.221's password: 
deepin@192.168.50.128's password: 
ls -liart | tail -n5 | grep 0001: No such file or directory
```

But it promotes "No such file or directory", is there other workaround?

Comment: There probably is, but could you explain in more detail what exactly you want to accomplish? If I interpret your command line correctly, you want to copy the last five files in your directory, but among them only those starting with "0001". I am not sure that this _really_ is what you want, and even then, you should **never** use the output of `ls -l` to generate a list of files to be copied.

Comment: @AdminBee Yes, that is what I want. why using `ls -l` is a bad idea? and is there any other ways?

Comment: Did you _actually_ use backticks in your command, or did you use single quotes around the pipeline?  Also note that if the command substitution worked, `scp` would not know what to do with the long listing output of `ls`.  Can you describe what you want to achieve with your pipeline? It looks as if you want to transfer the files that contain `0001` out of the five most recently modified files.

Comment: The reason why the output of `ls -l` is a bad idea is that any command to which you pipe this result would take _all_ output tokens as single input parameters, so `scp` would first look for a file called `51384328`, then trip on `-rw-r--r--` which it might interpret as a parameter (see e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548700/why-would-the-command-ls-generate-an-error-about-invalid-options)) etc. Leaving aside you will always be told "never to parse the output of ls", you must at least pipe the output through `awk` to select only the last column containing the filenames.