# Awk Using NR to output iteration number

Tags: bash, awk

I am looping through a list of files, extracting the final line, and printing out columns 8, 9, and 10.  I need to also print to the output the 'event number', which is essentially the total number of records being processes (NR).
How do I print the event/record number in the first column, outputting to the output file, such as what I have below?

```
for i in `ls -d *mcp`; do
tail -1 "$i" | awk  '{ printf "%s %s %s\n", $8, $9, $10}' >> ${Pout}${output}
done
echo "Finished Looping through each file."
```

What I want as the output is:

```
1 45 60 5
2 30 67 3
3 40 12 4
.
.
.
```

where the '45 column represents $8, 60 represents $9, and 5 represents $10.  the 1,2,3, etc. is what I need to output.  I essentially need to print the line number.

Comment: When I use this for loop structure:  
`for i in `ls -d *mcp`; do
 tail -1 "$i" | awk  '{ printf "%d %s %s %s\n",NR, $8, $9, $10}' >> ${Pout}${output}
done`

I get the following output:
`1 -0.242 125.104 35.0
1 -6.308 151.717 28.1
1 13.764 144.429 130.0
1 -56.022 -27.779 109.3
1 -9.461 156.412 4.0`

Instead of all ones in the first column I want 1,2,...n.  Does that clear things up?

Comment: I understand your suggestion.  However, that line in my for loop was working for me, which is why I didn't change it.  Yes, it may be longer than what you wrote, but I didn't change it because it did what I needed it to do.

Comment: Using backtics and ls means you are using two unnecessary processes. See whether my proposals below work for you.

Comment: (1) [Don’t parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  `for i in \`ls -d *mcp\`` isn’t just inefficient; it produces ***wrong results*** if filenames contain certain special characters.  (2) Don’t post multi-line commands or output in comments.  Clarifications to the question, to include things that you’ve tried, results that you’ve gotten, and results that you want, belong *in* the question — [edit] the question to put them there.  (3) When you do use command substitution, use `$(…)` instead of `\`…\``.  (4) If you must display a `\`` in code in a comment, type `\\``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in ./*.mcp; do
    if [ -f "$i" ]; then
        tail -1 "$i"
    fi
done | awk '{ print NR, $8, $9, $10 }'
```

Comment: This solution works! Is it correct that the if statement checks if the file exists, then it performs the 'tail' command?  Thank you.

Comment: @user78872: Yes, exactly.  On a side note: you can also "add line numbers" to a file with `cat(1)`, like this: `cat -n file`.

Comment: Can you identify any situation in which `for i in *mcp` fails (i.e., any reason why one should use `./` in that context)?

Comment: @G-Man: _Any_ situation?  Say if one of the files in named `-foo.mcp`.

Comment: Well, I believe that the "right" way to handle that concern is to say `tail -1 -- "$i"`, but I suppose that `for i in ./*mcp` is an effective way of handling it.

Comment: @G-Man: Well, back in the days when I worked on Apollo workstations (before Apollo was bought by HP), `tail`, like most other utilities, didn't accept `--`.  But, other than old dogs vs. new tricks, there's an informative [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110756/111878) about (among other things) the difference between `--` and `./*`.

Comment: @lcd047: Interesting post.  Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk` (version 4.x) try this:

```
awk 'ENDFILE { printf "%d %s %s %s\n", ++c, $8, $9, $10}' *mcp > "${Pout}${output}"

echo "Finished Looping through each file."
```

With other `awk`s and shells like `bash` try:

```
for f in *mcp
do
    awk -v c="$((++c))" 'END { printf "%d %s %s %s\n", c, $8, $9, $10}' "$f"
done > "${Pout}${output}"

echo "Finished Looping through each file."
```