# How to loop on my files to find a file that have an exact expression at the beginning of a line?

Tags: sed

I'm looking for a script that read all my files and find those which have `int tube[2]`
written at the beginning of any line, I should use

```
sed -e 's/Ancien/Nouveau/g' nomFichierEntrée > nomFichierSortie
```

But how to loop on my files?

```
for int i in ls do
    sed '^int tube[2]'
loop?
```

or am I missing something?

And how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -l '^int tube\[2]' ./*
```

Would list the non-hidden files in the current directory that have at least one line that starts with `int tube[2]`. The `[` needs to be escaped as it's a regexp operator.

In any case, [parsing the output of `ls` is generally a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Why do you use `./*` and not `*`? Is there any gain in using the first one?

Comment: @mohammad.k, see for instance [What is the difference between "du -sh \*" and "du -sh ./\*"?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110750)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $( ls ); do
.
.
.
done
```