# How can I test my shell script's file-handling robustness?

Tags: shell-script, error-handling

I've written a shell script that handles some "regular" filenames, but I've read [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and I'd like it to be more robust and handle any valid filenames (and/or directory names). How can I create a test-bed of files and directories to run my script against?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a separate directory to play in (for ease of cleaning up later, mainly); this uses the value of `$TMPDIR` if it's set, otherwise `/tmp`:

```
mkdir "${TMPDIR-/tmp}/testing"
cd "${TMPDIR-/tmp}/testing"
```

Create files that are separate, but appear similar to each other because of whitespace (space, tab, newline, carriage return, backspace):

```
touch -- a b 'a ' 'b ' 'a b' 'a  b' $'a\bb'
touch -- a$'\xe2\x80\x82'b a$'\xe2\x80\x83'b a$'\t'b a$'\n'b a$'\r'b
```

Credit for the above to [Patrick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128987/117549). The two hex code ones are UTF-8 space separators known as [nut](https://codepoints.net/U+2002?lang=en) and [mutton](https://codepoints.net/U+2003?lang=en); "in bidirectional context it acts as White Space and (are) not mirrored. The glyph(s) can, under circumstances, be confused with 20 other glyphs."

Create a plain file and one that would expand to the first if it was treated as a glob:

```
touch -- x '[x]'
```

Credit for the above to [Wumpus Q. Wumbley](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129070/117549).

In a similar vein:

```
touch -- 'a?b' 'a*b'
```

Credit for the above to [dave_thompson_085](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/59699/dave-thompson-085) in the comments here.

```
touch -- foo\`echo\ malicious\`bar
```

Credit for the above to [godlygeek](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/130644/117549).

A filename that will expand to something different (and potentially arbitrary execution!) if evaluated in a shell context:

```
touch '$( echo boom )'
```

Use:

```
touch -- single\'quote double\"quote back\\slash
```

to catch attempts to put a file name in quotes without escaping quotes.

```
touch -- -a -b -c -r -R - a=x
```

Credit for the above to [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110756/117549).

Create a named pipe and symlink (to create files that aren't "regular"):

```
mkfifo fifo
ln -s a alink
```

Create subdirectories that have various whitespace included in their names, along with token files inside of them:

```
mkdir subdir "subdir 1" "subdir 2" "subdir 3 " subdir$'\n'4
touch subdir/file0 "subdir 1"/file1 "subdir 2"/file2 "subdir 3 "/file3 subdir$'\n'4/file4
```

Create filenames only containing `*` (possibly problematic to remove), a filename consisting of only a (regular!) space, a dead symbolic link, a symbolic link that loops onto itself, and a sub-directory with a link back to the parent directory:

```
touch -- '*' '**' '***' ' '

ln -s /does/not/exist dead

ln -s loop loop

mkdir subdir_with_link
(cd subdir_with_link && ln -s .. parent)
```

More misc filenames.  The last two are unicode for "fractional slash" and "division slash".

```
touch -- '(' '!' '!!'  $'\xe2\x81\x84' $'\xe2\x88\x95'
```

Ideas from [Scott](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/23408/scott):

```
touch -- '-' '--' ';' '&' '|' '<' '>' '$' ')' '{' '}' = \\ '!' '#' '{a,b}'
```

Characters that are harmless in some locales but dangerous in others:

```
touch $'X\xa0Y' # non-breaking space in iso8859-1 which is considered
                # "blank" and "space" in some locales

touch $'\xa3\x5c' $'\xa3\x60' # α and ε in BIG5 or BIG5-HKSCS charset, but
                              # �\ and �` in ASCII
```

Characters that sort the same in some locales:

```
touch ① ② # sorts the same in GNU locales, order non-deterministic.
```

Files that escape the `.[!.]* *` glob (sometimes used to expand both hidden and non-hidden files):

```
touch ..foo ...
```

Comment: yes, please describe the test cases your creating most are obvious, some like that one which looks like a Unicode character in it, aren't.

Comment: I'd add `a?b` and `a*b` (quoted of course). @muru: byte sequences E2 80 82/83 are the UTF-8 encoding of U+2002 EN SPACE and U+2003 EM SPACE

Comment: Some evil geniuses at work there :-c

Comment: It might be interesting to play with `-` and `--`, although, depending on the script's requirements, it should maybe be impossible to access them without a leading `./`.  And I'm surprised that there are so few with non-glob shell special characters, like `;`, `&`, `|`, `<`, `>`, `$`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `=`, ``\``, `!`, and `#` — for example, `{a,b}`.

Comment: Feel free to add in your ideas, @Scott ! That's why I made it community wiki.