# How to create file with special characters without using quotes

Tags: shell

I am trying to make a file with special characters. But I don't want to use double or single quotes.

How can I make the file ?

Comment: Just use escaping (maybe with hex codes).

Comment: Are you talking about the _name_?  Or about the _contents_?  What kind of special characters?  Shell metacharacters?  Non-Latin-1 characters?  Control codes?  You are talking about doing this from shell script, ne?  Please [edit] your question to make all of these missing and ambiguous parts clear.

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347484/117549

Comment: I'm curious why you can't use single or double-quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Backslash provides with another form of quoting in Bourne-like shells, so you can do:

```
printf %s \$\ \; > file
```

For instance to have file contain those 3 (`$`, space and `;`) special characters. You can also use octal sequences in `printf` to specify exact byte values:

```
printf \\1\\2 > file
```

Makes a file with bytes 1 and 2. Some `printf` implementations also support hex sequences:

```
printf \\xff\\x80 > file
```

Or specifying characters with their Unicode code point:

```
printf \\u20ac > file
```

For the euro sign for instance. In most implementations, the character will be output in the locale's character set. An exception is the `printf` builtin of `ksh93` which outputs it in UTF-8 regardless of the locale's charset.

See also here documents for another way to enter text. That's convenient for multi-line text:

```
cat << \EOF > file
some text with $ \ | # *
and anything you want
EOF
```

To create file *names* with such characters, use:

```
echo text > \$\ \;
```

or:

```
echo text > $(printf \\1\\2)
```

etc. Note that as `$(...)` is subject to split+glob, you need to disable it with:

```
IFS=; set -o noglob
```

For characters that are otherwise in `$IFS` or glob operators (`*`, `?`, `[...]`).