# bash Split a list of file and run a command on each group

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

I am a super beginner with bash and coding in general so bear with me. I have a list of files (>1000) and I need to convert them to another format. However I need to run the command on 40 files a time.

Here is what I tried (but it basically run the command as there was nothing before, the xargs is not working).

```
path=/home/dir1/dir2/dir3;
ls ${path} >> ${path}/LIST;
FILES=${path}/LIST;
xargs -n 40 <<$FILES | xargs commandname
```

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is on reading your list:

```
FILES=${path}/LIST;
```

should be

```
FILES=$(<"${path}/LIST")
```

However,

- You could also let `xargs` read the file directly: `xargs -a "${path}/LIST"`.
- You don't need duplicate `xargs` at all.
- You should always double quote your filename variables!
- Your script has a lot of issues if your paths contain spaces or newlines.
- Add `-r` to `xargs` to prevent running your command without arguments if no files found.

---

Anyways,

**[Don't parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).**

You should use an array instead.

Also, it's good habit to use `\0` as delimiter together with `xargs -0` to prevent issues with newlines as part of file names.

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob # avoid `*` as file if no files found in $path
path=/home/dir1/dir2/dir3
files=("${path}"/*)
printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" | xargs -0 -r -n40 commandname
shopt -u nullglob
```

OR use `parallel` instead of `xargs`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
parallel -j1 -n40 commandname ::: /home/dir1/dir2/dir3/*
```

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`.

```
autoload zargs
zargs -rl40 -- /home/dir1/dir2/dir3/*(nN) -- commandname
```

(`n` for `numericglobsort` for a sorting order which is generally better for numbered files (so `file10` be sorted *after* `file2` for instanace), and `N` for `nullglob` (so it doesn't complain if `/home/dir1/dir2/dir3/*` does match and file when `/home/dir1/dir2/dir3` doesn't contain any non-hidden file or is not readable)).

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work, without needing to use GNU extensions.

```
set -- # clear positional arguments
for file in /home/dir1/dir2/dir3/*
do
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue
    set -- "$@" "$file"
    if [ "$#" -eq 40 ]
    then
        commandname "$@"
        set --
    fi
done
# in case the number of files is a number not divisible by 40
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && [ "$#" -lt 40 ]
then
    commandname "$@"
fi
```

I don't know what the command is, but when I made a function like

```
commandname()
{
    printf 'received %d arguments\n' "$#"
    printf 'listing received filenames\n'
    counter=0
    for par in "$@"
    do
        counter="$(( counter+1 ))"
        printf 'argument number %d: %s' "$counter" "$par" | LC_ALL=POSIX tr -d '[:cntrl:]'
        printf '\n'              
    done
}
```

it showed a proper number of them received, and listed all of them correctly, as far as I have seen. I tested that on most of the filenames listed here [How can I test my shell script's file-handling robustness?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347484/how-can-i-test-my-shell-scripts-file-handling-robustness) (53 files).

It's also worth noting that this won't find hidden files (ones that start with a dot), but what you wrote in OP doesn't either, so I assume that's fine. If you want only regular files, change `-e "$file" ]` to `[ -f "$file" ]`.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
find /home/dir1/dir2/dir3 -maxdepth 1 -print0 |
  xargs -0 -n 40 -P 0 commandname
```

Note that if the number of files is not a multiple of 40, one of the `commandname` process would not run with 40 arguments.